# Anyone know a dynamic lyric display application for mpd that works on Arch Linux?

Tags: software-rec, music, music-player, mpd

I'm looking for a dynamic lyric display app, not like in sonata, static display in a tab, but dynamic ones, show corresponding lines as the music plays

Comment: You're looking for karaoke software?  And you'd need the *data*, i.e. timed lyrics; I suspect there's no `mpd`-pluggable solution to this...

Comment: You will probably need to write your own... Check [PyKaraoke](http://kibosh.org/pykaraoke/) for a start.